# db2 aggregates and case when conditions giving repeated values and incorrect data

Tags: sql, db2-400

I have a simple query with a join that is correctly returning information about products:

```
select
            t1.category,
            t1.color,
            t1.size,
            t2.aisle

from infoTable t1

inner join locationTable t2 on t1.aisleNumber = t2.aisleNumber;
```

This returns

```
category  |  color  |  size  |  aisle
--------------------------------------
A             Red       S        F12
B             Blue      M        G18
C             Green     L        H9
D             Yellow    XL       D19
```

So far, so good.

Now, I want to join a table that tells me which stores have each product, and how many of each product are there. I'm manually checking these products at each store in the other table to make sure my data is accurate.

```
select
            t1.category,
            t1.color,
            t1.size,
            t2.aisle,
            count(case when t3.storeNumber = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as storeNumber11
            count(case when t3.storeNumber = 31 then 1 else 0 end) as storeNumber31
            count(case when t3.storeNumber = 41 then 1 else 0 end) as storeNumber41

from infoTable t1

inner join locationTable t2 on t1.aisleNumber = t2.aisleNumber
inner join storeTable t3    on t1.category = t3.category and t1.color = t3.color and t1.size = t3.size

group by t1.category,t1.color,t1.size,t2.aisle,t3.storeNumber
```

I'm close, but the results are incorrect. I get this:

```
    category  |  color  |  size  |  aisle  |  storeNumber11 |  storeNumber31  |  storeNumber41
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    A             Red       S        F12         17                 17                  17
    B             Blue      M        G18         12                 12                  12
    C             Green     L        H9          14                 14                  14
    D             Yellow    XL       D19         16                 16                  16
```

I know for a fact after manually checking that the first row should have 17 for storeNumber11 but zero for 31 and 41. The second row should have zero for storeNumber11 but 12 for storeNumber31.

So the fact that I get no zeroes and only get the same value repeated shows me that something is obviously off. I'm getting the correct number of rows and info otherwise, but how can I fix this to properly give me a count of only those store numbers if the join to t3 is satisfied?

Answer (score 3):

Use `sum()`, not `count()`:

```
select
        t1.category,
        t1.color,
        t1.size,
        t2.aisle,
        sum(case when t3.storeNumber = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as storeNumber11
        sum(case when t3.storeNumber = 31 then 1 else 0 end) as storeNumber31
        sum(case when t3.storeNumber = 41 then 1 else 0 end) as storeNumber41
. . .
```

`count(<x>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  `0` is just as non-`NULL` as `1`.